# Add Products Manually Configuration Button Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product

Add Products Manually Button in configuration is not working properly.

I already create simple products in my admin catalog, but in during configurable product when i configure simple product then i'm facing trouble. Add Products Manually Button is not showing. when i create new simple product from configure > attribute and then select attribute and after finish this long process complete then (Add Products Manually Button) is showing and then i can select my own simple products. Please help me regarding about this issue. i'm wasting too much time due to this long process.

Please check below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**This is known bug and Magento has already added this in their to do 2.3.**

> Here is the github bug reported link -
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5172

But as of now you can do the steps given on this link - https://gpmd.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002507803-How-to-manually-add-simple-products-to-a-configurable-product

Comment: Right now i'm working with this process but it's too long process and time wasting. That's why i need Add Products Manually button on first load.

Comment: No solution there..everyone just going to update magento version. :(

Comment: Can you guide me how i can update my magento version without any change in database ? right now i'm using 2.1.2

Comment: Then any change should be happen in my theme code ?

Comment: @WajahatBashir - no - only change happen with magento core files and few columns of tables(might be)

Comment: ok i'm trying now.

Comment: @WajahatBashir - okay fine - if you found answer is helpful - do marked as accepted and upvote it so other user gets helped !! Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this?